# connecting to sql server express remotely

Tags: sql-server

i have a beginners question, and i apologize if it is stupid.

i am a beginner at sql server. i can do sql pretty well, but i dont know much about connecting.

i have:

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and SQL EXPRESS
```

what is the process of allowing remote connections to it?

i would like to leave my laptop online at home with the management studio running and would like to access my home sql server through a remote connection.

i would like to know

1. how do i allow one of my databases to accept remote connections?
2. what would the connection string be? just my laptop's IP address or what?
3. is it dangerous to accept remote connections?

i have done the following BTW:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2005/05/05/415084.aspx

and when i do this it works:

```
SQLCMD -e -s localhost\sqlexpress,2301
```

however when i try to do this it does NOT work

```
sqlcmd -e -s my.ip.add.ress\sqlexpress,2301
```

anyway, after i do get this to work how would i connect to a specific db??

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want to (1) use Mgmt Studio interactively from a remote location, or (2) do you want some application to make database calls to the SQL Server on your laptop at home?

Comment: @sasfr in fact, both would b e great!

Comment: @sasfrog you there my friend?

Comment: @jenny: If you simply want to access your home PC, then use some software like Team Viewer or VNC :)

Comment: @ranhiru please stick to the specifics in the question

Comment: @jenny: first you'll need to make sure SQL Server is set up for remote TCP/IP connections. Launch the SQL Server Surface Area Configuration utility application (will be in the same place as Mgmt Studio .exe). Can't recall the specifics but make sure that you have it configured to allow remote TCPIP. @rnahiru's suggestion applies to your note that you'd like to use Mgmt Studio interactively - some sort of remote desktop technology is appropriate for this. Also, not sure if you'll have more success over at SuperUser or ServerFault for this one?

Comment: @jenny: Am i not sticking to one of your requirements? You wanted to access Mgmt Studio interactively from a remote location... So TeamViewer of VNC would do that

Comment: @ranhiru: please see #2 and #3 thank u very much BTW for your help

Comment: @sasfrog: thanks! what about 2 and 3?

Comment: Can you connect (telnet, ping) to your home PC from outside at all? Most ISP providers do not permit it.

Comment: @vgv8 i was trying to connect to my computer using the same machine, and the external IP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, SQL Server Express 2005 and 2008 not allow connections from anywhere but the local computer... but it is not difficult to change it.

In short, you want to run the **SQL Server Surface Area Configuration** program and enable the appropriate remote connection options you need.

You will also need to enable the SQL Browser service, and don't forget to poke the appropriate holes in your Windows Firewall if you have it enabled (which I hope you do). All three of these steps are described [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277). Good luck!

Comment: understood, but please tell me how can i connect to it

Comment: As you showed, it is working locally but not from remote. The most likely cause of the problem, then, is an interfering firewall--either your local Windows Firewall is still blocking (try allowing port 2301 through), or there's another NAT firewall between your remote connection and the server (e.g. your server is at home behind a Linksys/NetGear/whatever router, so it has an unroutable IP address like "192.168.1.2" which you cannot get to from the Internet).